# Problemas con punteros

Tags: c, punteros

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){

    char *palabras[5] = {"ab","cd","fg","hi","jk"};
    printf("%s",palabras[0]);

    return 0;
}
```

Mi pregunta es, ¿cómo emulo lo de la linea 4 pero usando un `scanf`?
Pero para guardar a un puntero x informacion

Como para poder comparar un puntero x con la primera posicion del puntero `palabras`.

Answer (score 1):

Al usar `scanf` entonces el tamaño de cada cadena no es conocido en tiempo de compilación y, en consecuencia, tienes que indicar manualmente el tamaño máximo del cada posición del array.

En este caso, como las 5 cadenas tienen 2 caracteres, se podría usar un array de tamaño 3 (2 caracteres + caracter nulo).

Finalmente necesitas un bucle para rellenar las 5 cadenas:

```
char palabras[5][3];
for( int i=0; i<5; i++ )
{
  scanf("%s", palabras[i]);
}
```